# How I disable the Tag creation on Maven Release Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm making my first project with Maven, and I don't wanna that the Maven create the Tag, because I don't use it.

How I'll make it?

Tks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described by the [update-versions goal](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/update-versions-mojo.html)

> Update the POM versions for a project. This performs the normal version updates of the release:prepare goal without making other modifications to the SCM such as tagging.

Looks like that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Realy, I'll test it, maybe I don't need to use the release:prepare. Soon I'll post here the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work, because, I need to generate the Jar and War with Jenkins

Comment: Use several goals in command to build jar,war: mvn release:update-versions clean install

Comment: Seems that the option you suggested only works for subversion, not for git

Comment: This should be unrelated to any SCM. So if you think there's an issue, please create a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE describing how we can reproduce your issue.