# Maven auto increment release version

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I am working on an initiative to auto increment the `X.Y.Z` version during the build process. In this case we are not removing the `SNAPSHOT` suffix (to make it a released version), rather increasing the minor part of the version:

- `X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT` => `X.Y.Z+1-SNAPSHOT`
- **NOT** `X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT` => `X.Y.Z`

I cannot use the maven release plugin since it is ONLY capable of cutting off `SNAPSHOT` suffix to make it released versions. So, I ended up creating a custom script which has the logic to increment versions.

My question here is how can I best implement the following steps:

1. Check out the `pom.xml` from perforce.
2. Run the custom script to increment version.
3. Commit the `pom.xml` change if deployment was successful.

I created a maven profile `autoversion` which partially meets the above needs. Maven first increments the version as part of generate resources phase. However, it ends up deploying the older version of the project.

```
mvn -Pautoversion clean deploy

         <profile>
        <id>autoversion</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                      <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                      <executions>
                                            <execution>
                                              <id>Calculate version</id>
                                              <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                              <goals>
                                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                              </goals>
                                              <configuration>
                                                    <executable>${basedir}/autoincrementversion.sh</executable>
                                                    <arguments>
                                                            <argument>-bdj</argument>
                                                    </arguments>
                                              </configuration>
                                            </execution>
                                      </executions>
                                    </plugin>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.9</version>
                                            <executions>
                                                    <execution>
                                                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                                            <goals>
                                                                    <goal>edit</goal>
                                                                    <goal>checkin</goal>
                                                            </goals>
                                                            <configuration>
                                                                    <username>jenkins</username>
                                                                    <basedir>./</basedir>
                                                                    <includes>pom.xml</includes>
                                                                    <message>Auto increment pom version</message>
                                                            </configuration>
                                                    </execution>
                                            </executions>
                                    </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building project 99.22.8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:1.3.1:set (default-cli) @ project ---
[INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
[INFO] Local aggregation root: /opt/project/auto-increment-release
[INFO] Processing com.project
[INFO]     Updating project com.project
[INFO]         from version 99.22.8 to 99.22.9
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.135s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Nov 05 23:15:13 PST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any pointers to achieve the requirement is highly appreciated.

Comment: I would say you should take a deep look into [Maven 3.2.1](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/release-notes.html) there is support directly from outsite via properties. See release notes `Continuous delivery friendly versions`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, good to know, but upgrade is not an immediate option now since we have to test various other factors.

Comment: @user6930, I'm not sure you are correct in this part that Maven Release Plugin is _"ONLY capable of cutting off SNAPSHOT suffix to make it released versions"_. It actually proposes to auto-increment the smallest significant number of the version. Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 1):

We are considering to actually use Maven Release Plugin (MRP) in similar situation changing ALL version numbers to something like `X.Y.Z.N`:

- `X.Y.Z` is *semantic* part which changes rarely during proper human-guided release
- `N` is *incremental* part (meaningless except sequence ordering) which MRP is able to increment automatically

Yes, MRP will create two additional commits (with released version and next `SNAPSHOT` version), but... If your developers make snapshot builds they need `X.Y.Z.N-SNAPSHOT` versions. And if you want incremental release, you also need `X.Y.Z.N` too. Hence, the same two commits.

All you may [avoid optionally is `X.Y.Z.N` tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18211691/441652) waiting for `X.Y.Z` only.