# maven-release-plugin, is it possible without tagging pom.xml with branch tag

Tags: maven, jenkins, cvs, maven-release-plugin

I am trying to create Jenkins job that performs release on my project using maven-release-plugin. First step of Jenkins job is checkout from CVS by tag x-x-x. The problem is that when maven-release-plugin changes version in pom.xml and tries to  commit file to CVS, commit fails (not tagging) because tag that was used during checkout is not branch tag:

```
cvs commit: sticky tag `x-x-x' for file `pom.xml' is not a branch
```

I would like to avoid creating branch tag for pom.xml just to satisfy maven-release-plugin. Is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I disable the Tag creation on Maven Release Plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18211411/how-i-disable-the-tag-creation-on-maven-release-plugin)

Comment: Why don't you want to tag your release on CVS?

Comment: and doing it the other way around? use the release plugin to create the tag for you?

Comment: @Tunaki I want to tag release because I am trying to make release maven-release-plugin way, in goal prepare one of the steps is "Tag the code in the SCM with a version name", see http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Comment: @gtonic problem is not during tagging, problem is one step before during commit

Comment: @wemu files that should be in release are tagged by developers. When preparing release project can't be check out by HEAD, it must be checked out by tag

Comment: In the end, in cvs you can only commit a file if you are on a branch, not if you are on a tag. So either you need to create a branch or you need to not commit the file.

Answer (score 0):

I have been sitting with this issue myself lately and it from what I can gather there is no way to release directly from a TAG. The reason being as you mention above.
Maybe a possible approach (still untested), could be to create a branch from your tag, setting your url to the newly created branch, releasing from branch.
Anyone who has the same scenario would be greatly appreciated.